# Which driver causes the BSOD Driver Power State Failure?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bsod, diagnostic

I get a BSOD with `DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE` on my Dell laptop running Windows 7 SP1. It got replaced once, but that one has the same error. The BSOD occurs only when it tries to awake from energy saving mode. Since the Dell support doesn't seem to help, I am looking into this myself. However, I cannot identify the driver that causes the BSOD.

I used `sigverif` to make sure I don't run unsigned drivers. I only run a VirtualBox Driver and an Intel HAXM driver from Android development, but both of them only were installed after the BSOD occured the first time.

Here are the two most recent minidumps:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ujrxj7sti0a5y7i/012716-7644-01.dmp?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1hr03mjpwyy775/021016-9625-01.dmp?dl=0

Which driver causes the failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither dump looks particularly conclusive, just listing a problem with "device object has been blocking an Irp for too long".

Looking into it, both dumps have mention of

```
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_e1d62x64_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_e1d62x64_IMAGE_pci.sys
```

where `e1d62x64` is the driver for an Intel Gigabit Adapter.

I would suggest finding out what network adaptor is in your machine (have a look in device manager) and [updating the drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/) for it to see if that resolves the fault.

A glance at the first dump gives a suspicion of BHDrvx64, a driver component of Norton Internet Security or Norton 360, though [this forum thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/110457-bsod-my-comp-2.html) kindof makes that seem a bit like a red herring.

The first dump:

```
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 7601.19110.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.151230-0600
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`03013000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`0325a730
Debug session time: Wed Jan 27 03:37:41.546 2016 (UTC - 5:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:47:32.872
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time (usually 10 minutes).
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: fffffa8006957060, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff8000518b3d8, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: fffffa8011902860, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

OVERLAPPED_MODULE: Address regions for 'BHDrvx64' and 'BHDrvx64.sys' overlap

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4ce7928f

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff88000e13000 pci

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff800`0518b388 fffff800`030f6820 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 fffffa80`06957060 fffff800`0518b3d8 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff800`0518b390 fffff800`0309206c : fffff800`0518b4c0 fffff800`0518b4c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x32450
fffff800`0518b430 fffff800`03091f06 : fffff800`0323cfe0 00000000`0002ca5b 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiProcessTimerDpcTable+0x6c
fffff800`0518b4a0 fffff800`03091dee : 00000006`a471dd90 fffff800`0518bb18 00000000`0002ca5b fffff800`03209de8 : nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0xc6
fffff800`0518baf0 fffff800`03091bd7 : 00000001`9e4025c1 00000001`0002ca5b 00000001`9e40254b 00000000`0000005b : nt!KiTimerExpiration+0x1be
fffff800`0518bb90 fffff800`0307e90a : fffff800`03206e80 fffff800`03214cc0 00000000`00000001 fffff880`00000000 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x277
fffff800`0518bc40 00000000`00000000 : fffff800`0518c000 fffff800`05186000 fffff800`0518bc00 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_e1d62x64_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_e1d62x64_IMAGE_pci.sys

Followup: MachineOwner
```

The second dump is effectively the same, without the mention of `BHDrvx64` so I will not repost it.

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't tell me explicitly which driver caused the crash?

Comment: @sinned I'm not completely familiar with the intricacies of crash dumps but I suspect it is because the minidump only captures the top level fault that caused the failure.  The faulting module is listed as `pci.sys` (`IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys`) but that is simply a driver that gets passed the IRP (I/O Request Packet) from the chain of drivers needed to make a device work.  It could be a sign of a bad driver or an actual hardware fault.  A minidump gives very little information besides exacly what happened at the moment of the crash, a full or kernel dump would be more helpful but also very large.

Comment: @sinned If you want to enable full or kernel level crash dumps and potentially do a bit of diagnostic yourself then howtogeeks has a nice page on how to go about it.  http://www.howtogeek.com/196672/windows-memory-dumps-what-exactly-are-they-for/ A full dump is likely to be several GB large and difficult to diagnose over the internet.  Another set of tools is listed at https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-analyze-memory-dump-dmp-file/  I am willing to help, but cannot download large files...

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will look into it when I find enough time...